# Footer Not Clearing on only one page

Tags: wordpress, footer

I'm installing a WP CMS (custom theme) on a page and the footer is clearing to the bottom on all pages except just this one:http://www.summer-band.com/?page_id=75.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you closed one or two divisions to much. Figure out which, best if your using a good IDE like netbeans...there you can find the missing `</div>` the fastest...

edit: this is what it looks like to me/was my first thought on this...

**edit 2: Got it: div id box and container are not closed.**

Because of this little friend here: `<!--<br />`. I Guess this happened in you content you added in the admin panel.

Comment: This is using the same page template pull as all of the other pages on the website, so I don't believe it's an unclosed <div> that's causing the problem.

Comment: Weird. That <br> doesn't show up in the admin panel, just in the source code when viewed in browser... strange. 

Thank you!

Comment: No Problem, glad i could help. And: It´s not about that break (<br>). The problem was the starting comment (<!--)